# Preventing bold text in download links in Sphinx Read the Docs

Tags: python, python-sphinx, read-the-docs

During documenting a python library using Sphinx and the RTD theme I was linking some PDF files for download using the `:download: Download Text <_download/the_file.pdf>` role but for some reason this results in links that look like:

Download **Text**

The first word is normal but all following words are boldface. This is just rather annoying. Is there a way to stop the boldface on the 2nd, 3rd, etc words in the download link text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here...

I have overridden theme styles before and so I did the same thing here.

I added a CSS file named theme_overrides.css to the _static folder in the Sphinx root directory with the contents:

```
/* override the bold words in download links */
@media screen and (min-width:767px) {

    .rst-content code.xref {
    /* !important prevents the common CSS stylesheets from overriding
         this as on RTD they are loaded after this stylesheet */
        font-weight: inherit !important;
    }
}
```

The only thing that worries me is that this might remove bold font in other places that use the .rst-content code.xref style. But so far I haven't found any.

Then add the following to the conf.py file for the Sphinx setup:

```
html_context = {
    'css_files': [
        '_static/theme_overrides.css',  # override bold download text in RTD theme
        ],
     }
```

*Credit to Rackspace Documentation Guides on http://rackerlabs.github.io/docs-rackspace/tools/rtd-tables.html for this solution.*